# ansible mapping an attribute back

Tags: dictionary, ansible, attributes

I am able to get the value when searching through list of dictionary but i am unable to use the selectattr and map the value back.
Any Clue where i am off

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    lacp_groups:
      - master: lacp0
        network: 10.65.100.0/24
        gateway: 10.65.100.1
        dns4:
          - 10.65.100.10
          - 10.65.100.11
        interfaces:
          - em1
          - em2
      - master: lacp1
        network: 10.65.120.0/24
        gateway: 10.65.120.1
        dns4:
          - 10.65.100.10
          - 10.65.100.11
        interfaces:
            - em3
            - em4

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: lacp_groups[0]
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.master }}"
      loop: "{{ lacp_groups}}"
      loop_control: 
        label: "{{item.master}}"
      when: "'em1' in item.interfaces"
    - set_fact:
        #myvar: "dns"
        myvar: "{{ lacp_groups | selectattr('interfaces','search','em1') | map(attribute='master') | join() }}"
    - debug:
        var: myvar
```

OutPut back is saying the followin

```
TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /mnt/c/users/jak_s/test12.yml:28
ok: [localhost] => (item=lacp0) => {
    "msg": "lacp0"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=lacp1)  => {
    "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"
}

TASK [set_fact] *************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /mnt/c/users/jak_s/test12.yml:34
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    ***"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred*** on ({{ lacp_groups | selectattr('interfaces','search','em1') | map(attribute='master') | join() }}): expected string or buffer"
}
        

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

I know I can retrieve the object by doing this

```
- set_fact:
        myvar2: "{{ item.master }}"
      loop: "{{ lacp_groups}}"
      loop_control: 
        label: "{{item.master}}"
      when: "'em3' in item.interfaces"
    - debug:
        var: myvar2
```

but i want to figure out the selectattr and map way of doing this in ansible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess: you are using ansible < 2.10. You have to cast the result of the map function to list in this case:

```yaml
myvar: "{{ lacp_groups | selectattr('interfaces','search','em1') | map(attribute='master') | list | join() }}"
```

This is not needed in ansible >= 2.10